# Importing android project as library project in another android project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I have created a project with help of Action Bar Sherlock. Now, I have made that project as library project and want that project to be included in another project which uses `appcompat`.

Here, I faced problem with `Error:(2) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined.` I googled and found some reference like we can use either  `ActionBarSherlock` or `Appcompat`.

What should i do to solve this issue. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733021/error-after-adding-dependencies-to-action-bar-sherlock-in-android-studio-0-5-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't use together ActionbarSherlock and Appcompat library.**

They use the same attributes.

Since the [Actionbarsherlock library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) **was deprecated** by the author 2 years ago, there is no need to use this library today.
Use the the **AppCompat library**

Comment: Completed ..Thanks for your support